# Recuperar o valor de um JTextField através de um ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

Sou um pouco novo em java e estava tentando entender os listeners. Por isso desculpem-me se o erro for simples.

Tenho um programa que cria uma interface gráfica simples e eu quero pegar o valor de um `JTextField` através de um `ActionListener`. Segue o código:

```java
public abstract class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Teste");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel texto = new JLabel("Nome: ");
        JTextField nomeField = new JTextField(60);

        panel.add(texto);
        panel.add(nomeField);

        Clique text = new Clique();
        nomeField.addActionListener(text);


        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tela.setContentPane(panel);
        tela.pack();
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tela.setVisible(true);
   }

}


class Clique implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        System.out.println(); //Quero imprimir o texto do campo aqui

    }
}
```

A questão é que eu não sei como referenciar o objeto do campo de texto para pegar o valor através de um `getText()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passar o campo necessário no construtor:

```java
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public abstract class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Teste");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel texto = new JLabel("Nome: ");
        JTextField nomeField = new JTextField(60);

        panel.add(texto);
        panel.add(nomeField);

        Clique text = new Clique(nomeField);
        nomeField.addActionListener(text);

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tela.setContentPane(panel);
        tela.pack();
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tela.setVisible(true);
   }

}

class Clique implements ActionListener {

    private final JTextField field;

    public Clique(JTextField field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(field.getText());
    }
}
```

Uma outra alternativa é usar um lambda (Java 8 ou superior):

```java
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public abstract class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Teste");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel texto = new JLabel("Nome: ");
        JTextField nomeField = new JTextField(60);

        panel.add(texto);
        panel.add(nomeField);

        nomeField.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println(nomeField.getText()));

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tela.setContentPane(panel);
        tela.pack();
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tela.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Uma terceira forma, caso você esteja no Java 7 ou inferior, é usar uma classe anônima:

```java
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public abstract class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Teste");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel texto = new JLabel("Nome: ");
        JTextField nomeField = new JTextField(60);

        panel.add(texto);
        panel.add(nomeField);

        nomeField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println(nomeField.getText());
            }
        });

        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tela.setContentPane(panel);
        tela.pack();
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tela.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

Comment: muito boa resposta, sobre o segundo método tem algum link que possa indicar com alguma explicação a mais?

Comment: @leandro17br Vê se este link te ajuda: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html - Se não ajudar, é só procurar no Google por "java lambda-expressions" que você deve achar bastante coisas.